# Prestashop: The following module(s) were not installed properly

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm creating a prestashop module, i have installed it correctly, but when i uninstalled it and tried to reinstall it, i got an error: the following module were installed properly, so how can i uinstall it even with database, thanks

```
<?php class BankAccountCustomer extends Module {

public function __construct() {

    $this->name         = 'bankaccountcustomer';
    $this->tab      = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version      = 1.0;
    $this->author       = '';
    $this->displayName  = $this->l('edit bank account for customer');
    $this->description  = $this->l('edit bank account for customer');

    parent :: __construct();

}
public function install(){
/* if(!$this->InstallDB())
return false;*/ 
 // var_dump($this->registerHook('displayBank'));exit();
if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('displayBank') 
|| !$this->copyOverride())
    return false;

 else
return true;
}
function InstallDB(){

$sql[] = 'ALTER TABLE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` ADD 
num_compte_bc   varchar(25)';   
$sql[] = 'ALTER TABLE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` 
ADD titulaire_compte_bc varchar(20)';   
$sql[] = 'ALTER TABLE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` ADD bank_name varchar(20)';
foreach($sql as $s){
$res =Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->execute($s);
if(!$res) return false;
}
return true;
}

function UnistallDB(){

$sql[] = 'ALTER TABLE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` DROP COLUMN num_compte_bc ';    
$sql[] = 'ALTER TABLE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` DROP COLUMN  
titulaire_compte_bc ';  
$sql[] = 'ALTER TABLE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` DROP COLUMN bank_name ';
foreach($sql as $s){
$res =Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->execute($s);
if(!$res) return false;
}
return true;
}



/*function uninstall(){
//if(!$this->UnistallDB())
//return false;
if(file_exists(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/override/classes/Customer.php')){
if(!unlink(_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/override/classes/Customer.php'))
return false; 
}
if (!parent::uninstall())
return false;
return true;
}*/     
function copyOverride(){

if(!copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/override/Customer.php' ,
 _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/override/classes/Customer.php' ))
return false;

return true;
}       

public function hookDisplayBank($params){
//  var_dump($this->display(__FILE__, 'accountbank.tpl'));exit();

return $this->display(__FILE__, 'accountbank.tpl');

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tarek, first of all you should use validator.prestashop.com to see where u are wrong.

Other thing, about overriding. You must put Customer.php in /my_module/override/classes/Product.php. It will automatically put override files to prestashop/classes/.

more about overriding: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors

And when you call uninstallDB function? You must add additional function like install: uninstall.

```
public function uninstall()
{
    Configuration::deleteByName('ML_SLIDER_LIVE_MODE');

    include(dirname(__FILE__).'/sql/uninstall.php'); or uninstallDB();

    return parent::uninstall();
}
```

First change this, validate your module to check if everything okey and try to install/uninstall.

Comment: What do you mean by You must put Customer.php in /my_module/override/classes/Product.php, i have done the copy in the install function, and i commented the uninstallDB call, where i have problem where the column doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by deleting class_index.php in the cache folder